# Find closest pair of numbers from csv file

Tags: python

I have a CSV file of info about minecraft building locations from a minecraft city server, In the csv file, I have 2 cords the x and z coordinates. I want to be able to enter cords nearby (in case I forget where a building is), and i need to scan the csv file for the closest coordinates to what I inputted. I think I might just overcomplicating this but I cannot figure it out. I know I need to pair the x and z together and compare them to the input value but I can't figure out how to do it.

[image]

I've tried googling answers and just trying to figure it out on my own. This is about how far I got on my own.

```
def FindClosest(x,z):
  with open('buildings.csv', newline='') as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f):
      xs = []
      zs = []
      xs.append(row[3])
      zs.append(row[4])
      closet_x = closest(xs, x)
      closet_z = closest(zs, z)
```

Comment: Compute the distance for each https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/geometry-plane/distance-two-points.php , save the lowest ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you want to calculate something based on CSV's, usually Pandas is your friend. It's an easy and fast way to perform calculations on your columns. Since calculating distances on a plance can be done by using Pythoras' Theorem, your problem can be solved with code like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

inp_x = 517
inp_z = 385

inp_rms = np.sqrt(inp_x**2 + inp_z**2)

arr = [[1, "Willis Tower", -517, -385], [2, "AGA Tower II", -266, -246],
    [3, "State Capital Building", - 236, 0], [4, "Pfister Hotel", None, None], [5, "CDOB Building", 102, 242]]


df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
df.columns = ["ID", "Name", "X", "Z"]
df.index = df["ID"]

df["x_diff"] = df["X"] - inp_x
df["z_diff"] = df["Z"] - inp_z
df["dist"] = np.sqrt((df["x_diff"]**2 + df["z_diff"]**2))


result = df["Name"][df["dist"].idxmin()]
print(result)
```

Instead of creating the arr with locations yourself, you can use `pd.read_csv(<path_to_csv>)` to open your file.